# SQL query Group By (Calculating Persistency)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a project in which I need to calculate persistency for agents policy, I need to fetch specific data from a table to store in another table so I need to write a 'MYSQL' query

here is the Table

[image: Persistency Table]

what I want is to group by column 'YEAR_MONTH' for every Agents so can calculate the sum of INFORCE_COUNT

Requirements:

1. Group by Column 'YEAR_MONTH'
2. Sum of Column INFORCE_COUNT
3. Repeating Agent_NO for every YEAR_MONTH (for unique 'YEAR_MONTH' in our case GROUP BY )

Please help thanking You.

Comment: And what is your problem/question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sum and  group by

```
 select agent_no, year_month, sum(inforce_count)
 from your_table 
 group by agent_no, year_month;
```

Comment: Looks Good, Thanks

Comment: If the answer is right .. please mark as accepted..

Comment: Reputation is not enough:)

Comment: mark as accepted .. is for all reputation also with reputation = 1 ..and you obtain 2 for accepting answer..

Comment: ok fine, I marked as accepted.